# Filtering out some element of a vector of tuples

Tags: julia

I have a very big vector of tuples and need to extract some of them  based on the some criteria (conditions).

That is, if the first and second elements of the tuple belongs to the other vectors we want to save them otherwise not. For example, considering the following where we have two vectors of vectors (i.e. starts and valid)

```
my_tuple = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 5), (5, 2)]
starts = [[2, 8, 3, 4] , [1,2]]
valid = [ [2,3,6,8], [1,3,4,5] ]
```

How can I only have those tuples in `my_links` where their `i` belongs to `start` and their `j` belongs to valid?

The desired output should be a vector of tuples like the following:

```
my_tuple = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 5), (5, 2)]
starts = [[2, 8, 3, 4] , [1,2]]
valid = [ [2,3,6,8], [1,3,4,5] ]
##############Would like an OTUPUT like:

[ [(2,3)], [(1,3) , (1,5), (2,3)] ]
```

Basically, what I'm trying to filter is that going through each pairs of vector ( in this case we have to pair`[2, 8, 3, 4] and [2,3,6,8] -- [1,2] and [1,3,4,5]` ) in start and valid vectors and then having those combination of them that make a tuple in `my_tuples`

I've tried to issue these commands but it's not useful, what can you suggest?

```
new_tuple = [(i,j) for (i,j) in my_links if ( i in starts && j in valid) ]
new_tuple = [(i,j) for (i,j) in my_links if ( i in starts , j in valid) ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> [filter(t -> t[1] in starts[i] && t[2] in valid[i], my_tuple) for i in eachindex(starts, valid)]
2-element Vector{Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}:
 [(2, 3)]
 [(1, 3), (1, 5), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Wow @Bogumił Kamiński Thanks a lot! Can you recommend me a source to read more on Julia command? for instance, I'm unfamilar with eachindex and want to know more to be better

Comment: When I ran the command the output is 2-element Vector{Tuple{Tuple{Int64, Int64}, Vararg{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}}: while yours is 2-element Vector{Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}}: Why?

Comment: I use `eachindex` instead of `zip` or `map`because `eachindex` will automatically check if both collections have the same length (`zip` or `map` would pick a length of the shorter collection). You can read about `eachindex` in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachindex. The reason that you have a different output is that in your question you first define `my_tuple` to be a vector of tuples with `my_tuple =[(...`, but in other place it is a tuple of tuples with `my_tuple = ((...` (note the `[` and `(` difference).

Comment: Very useful! Thank you @@Bogumił Kamiński